# Defining a Panel and instantiating it in a viewport

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to get Ext.define & Ext.create working in Sencha touch 2, so that I can define everything in my library and just create stuff pre-configured.

However, Ext.define is not doing what I would expect it to in anything I've tried.

Why does the following code not create a panel inside the viewport with the field label "Tame"?

```
Ext.define('mobi.form.Login',{
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'Tame',
            label: 'Tame'
        }
    ]
});
Ext.application({
    viewport: {
        layout:'fit'        
    },
    launch: function(){
        var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'name',
                    label: 'Name'
                }
            ]
        });
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('mobi.form.Login')); // This doesnt add anything to the viewport
        Ext.Viewport.add(form); //magically this works
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `Ext.define`, all configurations must go inside the `config` block. So your code should look like this:

```
Ext.define('mobi.form.Login',{
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',

    config: {
        items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'Tame',
                label: 'Tame'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

In general the only exceptions to this are:

- extend
- requires
- xtype
- singleton
- alternateClassName

Anything else should be inside the `config` object, but remember, *only* when using `Ext.define`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the sencha MVC concept but this is wrong if this is your only piece of code.

First create the following folder structure:

- MyAppFolder

  - index.html (include the sencha lib here)
  - app.js (main file)
  - app (folder)

    - controller

      - Main (main controller)
    - model (optional if no model is defined)
    - store (optional if no model is defined)
    - view

      - Viewport.js (your main viewport)
  - resources

    - css

      - style.css (your custom style)
    - images (your icons and images if you have)

Then in your app.js you would define something like this:

```
// enable loader for dynamic loading of .js classes
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true,
    paths   : {
    }
});

/**
 * Better performance is achived when knowing which .js classes we need to load prior to execution of this class.
 */
Ext.require([
]);

/**
 * This is the definition of our mobile application.
 * The name of this app is MVCTest.
 */
Ext.application({
    name        : 'MVCTest',

    controllers : ['Main'],
    views       : ['Viewport'],

    launch      : function() {
        Ext.create('MVCTest.view.Viewport');
    }
});
```

Then your main controller:

```
Ext.define('MVCTest.controller.Main', {
    extend  : 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config  : {
        refs : {
                viewport : 'mvctest-viewport'
            }
    }
});
```

Then your viewport would look something like this, according to your example:

```
Ext.define('MVCTest.view.Viewport', {
    extend : 'Ext.Container',
    xtype  : 'mvctest-viewport',

    config : {
        fullscreen : true,
        layout     : 'card',
        items: 
        [
           {
               xtype: 'textfield',
               name: 'name',
               label: 'Name'
           },
           {
               xtype: 'mvctest-tame'
           }
        ]
    }
});
```

By specifying the xtype `mvctest-tame` it will search for this xtype and add this in as a new item to this card. So you need the tame view:

```
Ext.define('MVCTest.view.Login',{
extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype: 'mvctest-tame',
items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'Tame',
        label: 'Tame'
    }
]
});
```

And do not forget to add the `Login` view to the app.js..

Comment: Kudos for a long answer, but it doesn't really address the issue.